# Uploading files on web server using multiple browser tab

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I'm currently working on uploading files to the web server(Dropbox). So far I've achieved this, but the problem is that how do i manage unique browser session when sending files from multiple tabs. In my case, if i have two tabs open and i submit form to load files, the first form to be submitted first, sends both the tabs uploaded files together. I'm using ajax to load ashx file for uploading.
As soon as the FileUpload1 controller is changed, the file is uploaded on the dropbox.

**Upload.aspx**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
                     swf: 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                     uploader: 'Upload.ashx',
                     cancelImg: 'Content/cancel.png',
                     auto: true,
                     multi: true,
                     method: 'POST',
                     //fileTypeExts: '*.jpg; *.png; *.gif; *.bmp; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.pdf; *.doc; *.docx;',
                     buttonText: 'Upload File',
                     width: 130,
                     onUploadSuccess: function (file, data, response) {
                         console.log("sucess");

                         console.log(data);

                         var filName = file.name + Math.random();
                         console.log(filName);

                         $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td><a  onclick=\"deleteHostTable(this);\"   href = 'javascript:;'>[x]</a></td></tr>");

                     },
                     onFallback: function () {
                         alert('Flash was not detected  or flash version is not supported.');
                         alert('Thats right')

                     }
                 });
             });


<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1"  runat="server" />
```